# Laravel 5: Check if a category collection has a valid result or no records at all

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

A very casual problem with the multi level DB tables and eloquent system.

> A MainCategory has more than one Category(`categories` table)
>
> A Category has more than one Product(`products` table)

Now the **routes.php** has:

```
Route::get('/categories/{slug}', ['as' => 'categories.list', 'uses' => 'ListController@getCategories'])->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
```

The **`ListController@getCategories`** method wants to list all **`products`** along with the **`categories`** come under the **`main_categories`**.

```
class ListController extends Controller
{
    public function getCategories($slug) {
        $categories = Category::orderBy('id', 'asc')
            ->select('categories.id as cat_id', 'categories.name as cat_name','categories.slug as cat_slug','products.*')
            ->join('main_categories', 'main_categories.id', '=', 'categories.main_category_id')
            ->join('products', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->where('main_categories.slug', '=', $slug)
            ->get();
        if(count($categories) >  0) {
            return view('pages.categories')->withCategories($categories);
        }
        else { // either main_categories.name not in $slug or there is no category available for this main_category

        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine as expected, listing both products and categories from the same collection object.

Now there is an else case. How could I check the result collection so that I can differentiate if there was a *main_category* in the name of given `$slug` or if there was no *categories* under the *main_category* with `$slug`.

See the code, `count($categories)` returns `0` for both cases. I don't stick on my eloquent way. You may suggest me another query or a condition check with PHP.
I will appreciate anything that helps me to prevent this into further complexity.

[PS:*All relations are direct and pretty basic(`belongsTo` and `hasMany`) and table names are in common standard- the Laravel 5 way of doing it(using v5.2). I guess you will get if there is a line of code needed/missing in my question. Feel free to ask if you still need anything.*]

Answer (score 0):

your query will give the result only if it finds the $slug in main_categories.slug otherwise it will not give any.

Comment: Why shouldn't anyone call `count` on an object? This is perfectly valid

Comment: no, this `if()` condition is always true! @abhishek

Comment: @eazysam did you try printing the result, are you getting any result from query or not.

Comment: `Collection {#279 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: Yes, so you arent getting any result out of query.
Can u tell what is the slug actually?

Comment: Well, I'm getting it right inside the **if condition**. The empty collection comes only for the else case. `$categories` has `'categories.id as cat_id', 'categories.name as cat_name','categories.slug as cat_slug','products.*'`.
Read the question once more if you still doubt. Why did you take back your code from the answer?